# Error in the return value of the stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have written a stored procedure and having a varchar(200) varibale as return variable, but in the output its showing as "conversion failed while converting varchar value to integer", in teh procedure im not converting to int, but im facing error

```
alter proc rulename @mfid varchar(20)
as
declare @ACF2 varchar(200)
begin 
if((select count(distinct(Rulename)) as count1 from MainframeExtractsPLP where      MFID=@mfid) > 0)
begin
set @ACF2='Apollo'
end
if((select count(distinct(Rulename)) as count1 from MainframeExtractsPLP where MFID=@mfid) > 0)
begin
set @ACF2= @ACF2 + 'GP'
end
if((select count(distinct(Rulename)) as count1 from MainframeExtractsPLP where MFID=@mfid) > 0)
begin
set @ACF2= @ACF2 + ',' + 'Tactical Comp'
end
if((select count(distinct(Rulename)) as count1 from MainframeExtractsPLP where MFID=@mfid) > 0)
begin
set @ACF2= @ACF2 + ',' + 'Unit Valuation'
end
if((select count(distinct(Rulename)) as count1 from MainframeExtractsPLP where MFID=@mfid) > 0)
begin
set @ACF2= @ACF2 + ',' + 'NPVS'
end
if((select count(distinct(Rulename)) as count1 from MainframeExtractsPLP where MFID=@mfid) > 0)
begin
set @ACF2= @ACF2 + ',' + 'Apollo Test'
end
if((select count(distinct(Rulename)) as count1 from MainframeExtractsPLP where MFID=@mfid) > 0)
begin
set @ACF2= @ACF2 + ',' + 'GP Test'
end
if((select count(distinct(Rulename)) as count1 from MainframeExtractsPLP where MFID=@mfid) > 0)
begin
set @ACF2= @ACF2 + ',' + 'Tactical Comp Test'
end
if((select count(distinct(Rulename)) as count1 from MainframeExtractsPLP where MFID=@mfid) > 0)
begin
set @ACF2= @ACF2 + ',' + 'Unit Valuation Test'
end
if((select count(distinct(Rulename)) as count1 from MainframeExtractsPLP where MFID=@mfid) > 0)
begin
set @ACF2= @ACF2 + ',' + 'NPVS Test'
end
return @ACF2
end
```

Answer (score 6):

The return value of a [stored procedure is an integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx). You should use an [output parameter instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx).

```
create procedure rulename
  @mfid varchar(20),
  @ACF2 varchar(200) output
as

-- Initialise param to empty string
set @ACF2 = ''

begin
  if ...
    begin
      set @ACF2 = @ACF2 + '...'
    end
  .
  .
  .
end
```